# Can I group or filter GCP billing by IAM principle, group or service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to see gcp services' (bigquery specially but others too) billing by users or groups. I know I can do by datasets by adding labels but I want to see further breakdown. I also know in biguqery monitoring I can see usage by users but it doesn't directly convert into billing. Such billing can show me cost or usage like compute engine, memory, networking per user. I understand not all usage will converge into billing but would be nice to see aggregated usage per user/groups/service account.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't feature like that. It's pretty hard to calculate. The byte billed are not always correlated to the real cost, especially when you use BI Engine or slots.

Answer (score 1):

As per @guillaume blaquiere, billing and usage tracking capabilities might not provide direct and granular billing breakdowns by user or service account for all services. Nonetheless, you can use other tool which involves analyzing your billing data like [setting up Cloud Billing Export](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery#setup).

You can also file for a [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) specifically regarding your use case, to be developed in the future and for more efficiency and optimization on both users and Google Cloud Services.